# Enable nuget package restore crash visual studio 2013 and 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package

[image]After I installed Visual Studio 2015, my NuGet package, and my visual studio 2013 this strange first when using "enable nuget package restore" visual studio breaks and freezes:

[image]

another thing is that the visual studio 2015 when creating any project also crash:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enable nuget package restore` is obsolete, use the [Automatic Package Restore instead](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore) instead. If you don't want automatic restore you can disable it in VS options.

Answer (score 0):

after I reasarch, Ifound:

1. Uninstall Nuget extension from Visual Studio 2015 RC
   [image]

2-Delete the folder in the directory showed below

[image]

3. Download the installation file of the older version of Nuget extension from this link: https://yadi.sk/d/BvJopnXOgF5rX
4. Extract the downloaded file to a folder on your machine.
5. Open Developer Commant Promt for VS 2015
   [image]
6. Type this command to install it: VSIXInstaller [your_extracted_folder_path]\NuGet.Tools.vsix /admin

Example: VSIXInstaller c:\nuget14_VisualStudio\NuGet.Tools.vsix /admin

Press enter to start installing

after use visual studio..

all credits go to: https://tndhuy.wordpress.com/2015/05/14/solved-nuget-package-management-problem-in-visual-studio-2015-rc/

Comment: why do you use such an old NuGet version? The newer versions removed it because this way is obsolte as I told you

Comment: ok, but the nugget was corrupcted, I´m not use a "enable nugget package restore" more, but nugget package is necessary to my app

Comment: why not install the latest NuGet version?

Comment: I install  Nuget extension from Visual Studio 2015 RC  in extensions and updates, after installed, I can´t install packages because visual studio is crashed, the solution was install manualy.. tks for your help..sorry for my english I´m Brasilian

Comment: what o you mean with RC? VS2015 Update 3 RC?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114259/discussion-between-igor-monteiro-and-magicandre1981).

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio froze when I loaded a particular solution.
By disabling nuget package manager it worked but I could no longer use nuget.
I have removed the .vs folder from the solution and since visual studio is loading well! :-)

Maybe this can help...